# xchart java swing not drawing data correctly when using updateOHLCSeries

Tags: java, swing, knowm-xchart

Hi I have a weird issue with xChat lib(org.knowm.xchart) in java swing.

I am able to create a chart(Candle) when I first time add data to it, but when I add data to it say 5 sec after it is not drawing the candles.

1. In Init i used `chart.addSeries("Candle", xData, openData, highData, lowData, closeData, volumeData);`
2. In Timer 5 sec after(done by using WSS onmessages i.e. the message is recieving after few seconds) `chart.updateOHLCSeries("Candle", xData, openData, highData, lowData, closeData, volumeData);`

Result:
[image]

I am not able to understand why it wors first time and not 2nd time, i suspect it has something to do with the chart.updateOHLCSeries but cannot find a solution for it.

In the image above, the first 5 candles are drawn using the chart.addSeries and last 2 are being addedd in using chart.updateOHLCSeries

Comment: You wrote in your question: _i suspect it has something to do with the chart.updateOHLCSeries_ Actually, I think it may have something to do with your code. Are you using [swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) ?

Comment: Hi i said timer to make things easy, but in actual I am getting data from WSS onmessages and they are consistently sending me data in every 5 sec.

Comment: @Abra I have updated the description with more details